# docker 急にFailed to lookup hostエラーが発生

Tags: docker

#### 状況

dockerでpullすると以下のエラーが発生します。どのイメージをpullしてもエラーになります。
docker hubにログインする際も同様のエラーが発生しました。
以前まで問題なく使用することができていて、特に変更したこともないので、思い当たる節がありません。
インストールし直しても解決しません。どなたか原因がわかる方いますでしょうか。

プロキシは利用してないので関係ないと思われます。
DNSの名前解決の問題だという記事が多かったのでいろいろ試しましたが、ダメでした。

#### 実行コマンド

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started
```

#### エラー

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": Failed to lookup host: siteproxy.
```

#### Docker Hubにログインしようとした時のエラー

```
Post "https://login.docker.com/oauth/token": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup siteproxy: no such host
```

#### 環境

Windows10
Docker for Desktop

Answer (score 1):

#### 解決方法

Settings/Resources/Proxies/Bypass proxy settings for these hosts & domains
の欄にsiteproxyと記入